# Need help refactoring code that checks for union between a list of users and the current users FB friends

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Got a page in my app that lists events the current user has added to their personal calendar.

For each event I'm checking to see if any of the current user's FB friends are among the other users on my site that have also added the event to their personal calendar.

It works fine...if you're willing to wait.

Because there's not quick way to check for the union of two arrays, that I'm aware of, I want to move this checking to a background job (Delayed Job on Heroku) and use AJAX to update the page as the job(s) are completed.

Not sure how to proceed...any tips, links, snippets or smart remarks are appreciated.

Please disregard the embedded styles and other stuff that can be improved...JUST getting started and for now I'm really just trying to solve this key issue because the performance hit of what I'm doing makes the app basically useless in it's present state.

**user.rb**

```
has_many :events_users
has_many :events, :through => :events_users, :order => 'start'
```

**event.rb**

```
has_many :events_users
has_many :users, :through => :events_users
```

**events_users.rb**

```
belongs_to :event
belongs_to :user
validates_uniqueness_of :event_id, :scope => :user_id
```

**show.erb.html**

```
<% @user.events.each do |event| %>

<h4 style="margin:0;"><%= link_to event.name, event %><% if @user == current_user %>  - <%= link_to 'X', remove_from_bucket_url(:id => event.id), :style => 'color:#cc0000;' %> <% end %><br/>
<%= event.start.to_s(:month) %> <%= number_to_ordinal(event.start.to_s(:day)) %> in <%= event.city %>, <%= event.state %></h4>

<% if current_user %>

  <a href="/users/<%= current_user %>"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<%= current_user.uid %>/picture" style="margin:10px 10px 20px 0px;" /></a>
  <% event.users.each do |user| %>
    <% @fb_user.friends.each do |friend| %>
      <% if friend.identifier == user.uid %>
        <a href="/users/<%= user.id %>"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<%= user.uid %>/picture" style="margin:10px 10px 20px 0px;" /></a>
      <% end  %>
    <% end  %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

<% end  %>

Answer (score 2):

What does @fb_user.friends do? The worst case scenario is that it's doing a call to a remote service for every user in an event.

If that's the case, you should reduce that to only one call.

I would suggest you intersect it like this:

```
<% @intersected_users.each do |user| %>
  <a href="/users/<%= user.id %>"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<%= user.uid %>/picture" style="margin:10px 10px 20px 0px;" /></a>
<% end  %>
```

In the controller:

```
@intersected_users = intersection(event.users,@fb_user.friends)

... 

def intersection(event_users, fb_users)
  my_ids = event_users(&:uid) 
  fb_users.select {|u| my_ids.include?(u.identifier) }
end
```

I believe that in this case your poor performance is associated with remote service calls.

Comment: I'm actually only making one call to the FB API to grab @fb_user...including an array of that users FB friends. Given an event with say 2,000 users and a current user with say 300 FB friends...that's 60,000 combinations I have to check.

Comment: Uhm.. If it's not an excess of remote service calls, I'd look into the intersection method.

Comment: Uh, you don't have to check 60,000 combinations... you have to check 300 (or the smaller of the two. for each friend, is the friend in the event attendees?). But anyway, the intersection method is the way to go, not looping through one (and definitely not looping through both!!)